# Insufficient device memory

Tags: insufficient-memory

my galaxy note SHV-E160S have 200 mb free device memory but still it donot even download 5 mb apps from play store and the warning message of insufficient memory displayed... Any so;ution???

Answer (score 1):

First download "Easy app backup and restore" app from app store.It will save all of your app apk file in your memory card.Now restore your phone(factory reset).After completion install app again from the folder where apk file is present. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try heading over to the Settings>Application Manager>Tap over the Google Play Store app and try clearing the cache and the data stored. Now again try opening the the play store and download the app it should start working fine.